# How to edit configuration files (part of Azure Cloud Services (Classic) files )on Remote Desktop?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-cloud-services

I have deployed Azure cloud service and it is working. In deployment files, I have app.config. I have to edit app.config and save it. I don't want to re-deploy cloud service again from Visual Studio. I am able to login in remote Desktop but don't know how to view file and then edit file. Any suggestion?

Comment: I agree that app.config can be edited. but where is this file located in remote desktop of Azure Cloud service. I mean to say where cloud service files are stored. I need path.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this can be done, but you should not do it except for testing purposes.  Any change you make via RDP will be lost and will revert back to whatever you deployed with your CSPKG.

For more information on editing a running cloud service see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2013/09/05/how-to-modify-a-running-azure-service/.  You can find your config files on E drive or F drive under sitesroot or approot depending on your role type.